# amsproc class, formating \cite command

Tags: spacing, citing

Using `\documentclass{amsproc}`, `\bibliographystyle{amsplain}`.

With `\cite{A,B}` one gets something like `[1, 2]`.
I would like to decrease the space (for example to thinspace) between `1,` and `2`.
I would appreciate any suggestion to do that simply,
i.e., by (re)defining a macro, instead using additional package.
But if a package is unavoidable, ok, but which one?

A minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{amsproc}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{testa,
  title= "Title A",
  author= "Author A",
  journal= "Journal A",
  pages= "1-2",
  year = "2012"
}
@article{testb,
  title= "Title B",
  author= "Author B",
  journal= "Journal B",
  pages= "2-3",
  year = "2012"
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite{testa,testb}
\bibliographystyle{amsplain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Without using additional packages, add the following lines to the preamble of your document:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@cite#1#2{{%
 \m@th\upshape\mdseries[{\bfseries #1}{\if@tempswa, #2\fi}]}}
\def\@citex[#1]#2{\leavevmode
\let\@citea\@empty
\@cite{\@for\@citeb:=#2\do
{\@citea\def\@citea{,\penalty\@m\,}%
\edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb\@empty}%
\if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi
\@ifundefined{b@\@citeb}{\hbox{\reset@font\bfseries ?}%
\G@refundefinedtrue
\@latex@warning
{Citation `\@citeb' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
{\@cite@ofmt{\csname b@\@citeb\endcsname}}}}{#1}}
\makeatother
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{amsproc}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{testa,
  title= "Title A",
  author= "Author A",
  journal= "Journal A",
  pages= "1-2",
  year = "2012"
}
@article{testb,
  title= "Title B",
  author= "Author B",
  journal= "Journal B",
  pages= "2-3",
  year = "2012"
}
\end{filecontents}

\makeatletter
\def\@cite#1#2{{%
 \m@th\upshape\mdseries[{\bfseries #1}{\if@tempswa, #2\fi}]}}
\def\@citex[#1]#2{\leavevmode
\let\@citea\@empty
\@cite{\@for\@citeb:=#2\do
{\@citea\def\@citea{,\penalty\@m\,}%
\edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb\@empty}%
\if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi
\@ifundefined{b@\@citeb}{\hbox{\reset@font\bfseries ?}%
\G@refundefinedtrue
\@latex@warning
{Citation `\@citeb' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
{\@cite@ofmt{\csname b@\@citeb\endcsname}}}}{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\cite{testa,testb}
\bibliographystyle{amsplain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

The output zoomed to 200%:

[image]

Using packages, you can simply load the [`cite`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cite) package:

```
\usepackage{cite}
```